# How can I hide v-btn?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
btn : false
```

```html
<v-btn value="false">1</v-btn>
<v-btn v-model="btn">2</v-btn>
```

I want to hide v-btn component.

but, v-btn 1 and 2 are visible.

It's impossible?

Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide html elements in vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308292/hide-html-elements-in-vuejs2)

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

you can define a property in your data () and use `v-show` or `v-if` depending on your needs
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/847/)